# How to indicate the directory where I am in Linux

Tags: linux, gnu

Hi I want to know the command to indicate the directory where I am . Suppose I am in home/subho . Now to indicate that directory let's for gnome-open I will write 
gnome-open ../subho

Is there any other command to indicate the directory currently I am .

Comment: use `pwd` command `pwd` means `print name of current/working directory`

Answer (score 3):

```
pwd
```

(print working directory).

Answer (score 0):

Subhankar, many ebooks and online resources are available on the net. 
Pick up a book on Unix scripting and you should be good to go.